# Adding a Pause to the Execution in C# application

Tags: c#

I have an application which read from a file and shows the contents of the file in popups. the text file contain data in such a way;

> D:\\abc\\xyz.txt|xyz.txt
>
> D:\\MP3\\boom.mp3|boom.mp3

Now the application reads a line from the text file and shows the line content in another form, and these popups are displayed at once, what i want to do is, if there are multiple lines then each popup is shown after a pause of 10sec, but Thread.Sleep(10000)is not working for me. the code to read is given below.

```
   void FileDetected()
    {
        int counter = 0,c=1;
        string line;
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FILEPATH);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] words = line.Split('|');
            c = 1;
            path = ""; fileName = "";
            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (c == 1)
                    path = word.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
                if (c==2)
                    fileName = word;
                c++;
            }
            counter++;
            if (path != "" && fileName != "")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Path :" + path);
                Console.WriteLine("FileName: " + fileName);
                popup dlg = new popup(path, fileName);
                dlg.Show();
                //Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }
```

kindly guide me.

Comment: I want to show each popup after 10sec not all at once

Comment: And what's the trouble you're having with Thread.Sleep?

Comment: popup form arises from the taskbar according to timer.. now if apply thread.sleep, it completly stops the thread execution and the popup never arise from the taskbar

Comment: Try Application.DoEvents and then perform the Thread.Sleep. This will pump all the windows messages through first.

Comment: @NeillVerreynne - Calling `Application.DoEvents` is a very bad practice and should be avoided almost entirely. It can lead to all sorts of re-entrancy issues.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I know, but should be fine for what the OP wants to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4.5 (or 4.0 with Visual Studio 2012 or newer by downloading [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async) via NuGet) it is very easy to do with async/await.

```
//You will likely need to modify the calling code to use async/await too.
async Task FileDetected()
{
    int counter = 0,c=1;
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(FILEPATH);
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] words = line.Split('|');
        c = 1;
        path = ""; fileName = "";
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (c == 1)
                path = word.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
            if (c==2)
                fileName = word;
            c++;
        }
        counter++;
        if (path != "" && fileName != "")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Path :" + path);
            Console.WriteLine("FileName: " + fileName);
            popup dlg = new popup(path, fileName);
            dlg.Show();

            //Pauses the loop for 10 sec but does not lock up the UI.
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }
    }
```